# adding elements of a list in a given way in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Some one helped me the below function but I need its inverse that means the below output will be the input of my functionand the below input will be the output of my function

```
conv = concat . f
where f [] = []
      f (x:xs) = map (x+) xs : f xs

 > conv [3,10,5]
 [13,8,15]

> conv [2,5,15,34]
[7,17,36,20,39,49]
```

Comment: Two objections: 1. The problem isn't fully specified. You give a relationship that maps three numbers to three numbers; it's relatively clear how to generalize it to map n numbers to n numbers, but then one of your input/output examples maps 6 numbers to 4 numbers. What? 2. You've shown no effort of your own, and so we can't direct you to a specific mistake you've made or misunderstanding you have.

Comment: This looks like some kind of convolution. I am not sure what the logic is though. In your second example there is no obvious way to solve it with the relations given.

Comment: Since this post has been put on hold and therefore won't accept my answer, here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/basile-henry/6a2bbfd9800e6d8968e37d39915e29af) of it.

Comment: I think this is a good problem, although not well articulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the inverse of this function

```
conv = concat . f
    where f [] = []
          f (x:xs) = map (x+) xs : f xs

> conv [3,10,5]
[13,8,15]

> conv [2,5,15,34]
[7,17,36,20,39,49]
```

I came up something like this.  Note that for length less than 3 there can't be a unique solution, handle that case...

```
solve x = (reverse . (h :) . map (subtract h) . map head . split') rx
        where rx@(a:b:c:_) = reverse x
              h = (a+b-c) `div` 2

> solve [7,17,36,20,39,49]
[2,5,15,34]

> solve [13,8,15]
[3,10,5]
```

you can check whether

```
conv . solve = solve . conv = id
```

split' scrolled up on my screen, it's defined as

```
split' = go 1
     where go _ [] = []
           go n x = take n x : go (n+1) (drop n x)
```

Comment: Yeah sir I am searching the inverse of that function, please can you help me about that?

Comment: Nice answer karakfa, I was working on a solution, which I have found. It is similar to your but not as concise. The post is however on hold and I can't post it. Way to waste time for nothing, thanks StackOverflow

Comment: Where is `split'` defined?

Comment: yeah sir thank you ,I can not find the definition of split' so where did you define?

Comment: sir karakfa thank you again but its giving an error in  go (n+1) (drop n x) please can you put the code completely at one time

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I have tested karakfa's code and it works!

Comment: Thank you sir karakfa its correct I am very happy the way you analyzed and understood my rough question because I did not know how I can define it. Nowadays people they don't have patient but fortunately there are few understandable and you are one of them. I appreciate it. God bless you. basile-henry thank you, I have seen your answer I appreciate that.